# triggering motherboard buzzer through c++ for morse code generation

Tags: c++, audio, command-line-interface, morse-code

Well I've gone back to basics and learning C++ from scratch as the last time I coded any it was years ago. Currently working under Windows cli until getting the Linux box on again. I'm using

```
cout << "\a" << flush;
```

to make my system create a noise but on looping, there is always a delay - not so good for making longer pulses. I know under C# and Basic there was a way to use the computers buzzer but do not know the c++ way. Any help please?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a standard way to control a computer's internal speaker.  How you would do so depends on which operating system you're working under.  Under the Windows API, there's a [Beep function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and under Linux, you can use [ioctl](http://www.linuxhq.com/guides/LPG/node83.html).  Your programming language has little to do with it; this is a library question.

Answer (score 0):

Windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx

For non-Windows, it's a little more complicated, but take a look at the source of the "beep" program for help, especially the play_beep() function and the beep_parms_t structure: http://johnath.com/beep/beep.c

Comment: Ahh yes it was beep I was looking for. Thats briniging back the memories now. I'll need to get into the documentation more. My thanks